# Javascript function to remove tailwind classes and generate a valid selector

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a code that creates a CSS selector by traversing through the dom to that particular element, but here lies the case I use tailwind, and sometimes the tailwind classes are causing a problem for me so I don't tend to get the element in the dom. For example something like this: `class="about_hero_text max-w-[530px] py-[15px] px-0 md:mt-3 md:px-6"` produces something like this `"div.about_hero_text.max-w-5b 530px5d.py-5b 15px5d.px-0.md3a mt-3.md3a px-6"` which as you can see is not right.

```
const oldSelector =
    'section#shopify-section-template--18077714481441__main > div.about-hero-wrapper.flex.justify-center.gap-x-5 > div.px-4.md3a px-6 > div.about_hero_text.max-w-5b 530px5d.py-5b 15px5d.px-0.md3a mt-3.md3a px-6 > div.about-hero-adb > a';
const newValidSelector =
    'section#shopify-section-template--18077714481441__main > div.about-hero-wrapper.flex.justify-center.gap-x-5 > div.px-4 > div.about_hero_text > div.about-hero-adb > a';
```

If you look at these two selectors you can see a pattern where I've removed some classes from it to make the selector valid and actually recognize it in the dom. can you detect the pattern or can I have a function that cleans it up? I have a function which needs improvement.

```
function fixSelector(oldSelector) {
  const classPattern = /(\.[\w\d-]+)(?=\s|\..*?\s|$)/g;
  const modifiedSelector = oldSelector.replace(classPattern, '');

  return modifiedSelector.trim();
}
const oldSelector = 'section#shopify-section-template--18077714481441__main > div.about-hero-wrapper.flex.justify-center.gap-x-5 > div.px-4.md3a px-6 > div.about_hero_text.max-w-5b 530px5d.py-5b 15px5d.px-0.md3a mt-3.md3a px-6 > div.about-hero-adb > a';
const newValidSelector = fixSelector(oldSelector);
console.log(newValidSelector); // i want something like this 'section#shopify-section-template--18077714481441__main > div.about-hero-wrapper.flex.justify-center.gap-x-5 > div.px-4 > div.about_hero_text > div.about-hero-adb > a';
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to generate this code which works just fine

```
function modifyString(str) {
  if (!str.includes(' > ')) {
    return str;
  }

  const stringCopy = [str.split(' > ')[0]];
  const strArr = str.split(' > ');

  for (let i = 1; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    const strArr2 = strArr[i].split(' ');

    if (strArr.length > 1) {
      const firstString = strArr2[0];
      const lastDotIndex = firstString.lastIndexOf('.');
      
      if (lastDotIndex !== -1) {
        const newStr = firstString.substring(0, lastDotIndex);
        stringCopy.push(newStr);
      } else {
        stringCopy.push(firstString);
      }
    } else {
      stringCopy.push(newStr);
    }
  }

  return stringCopy.join(" > ");
}

// Usage example
const str = 'section#shopify-section-template--18077714481441__main > div.about-hero-wrapper.flex.justify-center.gap-x-5 > div.px-4.md3a px-6 > div.about_hero_text.max-w-5b 530px5d.py-5b 15px5d.px-0.md3a mt-3.md3a px-6 > div.about-hero-adb > a';
const modifiedString = modifyString(str);
console.log("Modified string: ", modifiedString); // returns section#shopify-section-template--18077714481441__main > div.about-hero-wrapper.flex.justify-center > div.px-4 > div.about_hero_text > div > a and i can find it in the dom..
```

Before
[image]

After
[image]